# Loading api data after page initialization

Tags: angular, loading

I'm asking my first question on this forum because I've been stuck on it for a while.
I should point out that I'm not an Angular expert.

Do you know how to load a page, then one of the components inside?

For example, I have a page with a navigation bar and an API call component (which displays a table).
I'd like the page to load, we see the navigation bar, and only then the API call component is activated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ngAfterViewInit life cycle hook to ensure the statements are executed after view is completely initialized.

You can read more about that [here](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks)

Essentially, you will need to do ::

```
export SomeComponent implements AfterViewInit

ngAfterViewInit() {}
```

If you are placing nav-bar in seperate component and populating the api data in a separate component, please do the following ::

Inside your navigation component,

In HTML : you can place the `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`

In TS: Inside `ngAfterViewInit()`, do `router.navigate()`

Please add a comment if you feel you need more help on this :)

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer! I'm not sure I fully understood this ngAfterViewInit, especially the "router.navigate()".
The "router.navigate()" will load the component in the same page?
I'll give it a try.

Comment: Naah, If you want to load the api details as a separate component. You will need to render api component as child of navbar component.

Comment: Then you will have to place a <router-outlet> in nav bar html and do router.navigate in nav bar TS inside ngAfterViewInit()

Comment: Otherwise, you can use a single component and do the api call inside afterViewInit()

Comment: I didn't understand that. He had to be a child...
I'll do some tests for tomorrow, a little complicated but very interesting!

Comment: Any luck using ngAfterViewInit() ?

Comment: it seems to work, the ngAfterViewInit() is very interesting! I close the question thanks to you.

Comment: No worries mate. I'm glad it helped you 

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-simple-http-get) I threw together for you, just move the request piece accordingly into the needed lifecycle event.

I should mention, it would be best practice to move the actual request into a service and then from the component fire the request.

```js
import {
  Component,
  OnInit,
  AfterViewInit
} from '@angular/core';
import {
  HttpClient
} from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  todos: Array < Todo > ;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos').subscribe((data: Todo[]) => {
      this.todos = data;
    });
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log('ngOnInit');
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    console.log('ngAfterViewInit');
  }


}
export interface Todo {
  userId: number;
  id: number;
  title: string;
  completed: boolean;
}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer! 
I don't understand how html updates if the data is not present at the creation of the component.
Also, if I modify a variable initialized in the constructor, then modify in the ngAfterViewInit, is this going to be a problem?

Answer (score 0):

For those who use the router-outlet, and  tags for urls, for example in header, you can use the routerLink to load only the component inside (I discovered this recently).

By having a "home" path, for example you can :

```
<a routerLink="/home">Home</a>
```

Some docs:
*FRENCH*:
https://guide-angular.wishtack.io/angular/routing/mise-en-place-du-routing

*ENGLISH*: https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/activating-routes-with-routerllink-in-angular